# Picking up ID when grouping

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Suppose we have the following data set.

> ID C1 C2
>   1 - a - a
>   2 - b - b
>   3 - a - a
>   4 - a - b
>   5 - a - b
>   6 - b - b

I can execute the following statement:

```
select C1, C2 from Hazaa
group by C1, C2
```

However, I'd like to be able to get the value from *ID* column as well. Of course, I understand it's not possible just like that. My condition is that it's the lowest *ID* value in each groupings members that is listed.

I've tried googling for that but I think I'm expressing my request in a clumsy way because Google gives me nada, at least as far I can understand. The best hit is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) but, frankly, I'm not sure I understand how it's done. (I need it to work on 2005 but in the future we'll move to 2012 so if there's a neater trick there, I'd like to learn both ways.)

Comment: from the linked question; `first()` is not a valid SQl Server aggregate function, if you just want the lowest numerical ID, just use `MIN()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify which ID you want from within the group, this will show the first and the last for each group:

```
SELECT min(ID),max(ID),count(ID),C1, C2 from Hazaa group by C1, C2
```

you'll want `min(ID)`, but look at the other values so you can understand what is happening.

`group by` combines multiple rows in to a single one, you use aggregate functions like `min()`, `max()`, `count()` to get values per each group.

Sample code:

```
declare @Hazaa table (ID int,c1 char(1), c2 char(1))
insert into @Hazaa values (1 , 'a' , 'a')
insert into @Hazaa values (2 , 'b' , 'b')
insert into @Hazaa values (3 , 'a' , 'a')
insert into @Hazaa values (4 , 'a' , 'b')
insert into @Hazaa values (5 , 'a' , 'b')
insert into @Hazaa values (6 , 'b' , 'b')

SELECT 
    min(ID) AS MinID,max(ID) AS MaxID,count(ID) AS CountOf,C1, C2 
    from  @Hazaa group by C1, C2
```

OUTPUT:

```
      MinID       MaxID     CountOf C1   C2
----------- ----------- ----------- ---- ----
          1           3           2 a    a
          4           5           2 a    b
          2           6           2 b    b

(3 row(s) affected)
```